# Inequality of integrals involving $\exp$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, inequality, riemann-integration

Suppose that $p(a)\ge 0 $ and $\int_0^{+\infty} p(a)da = 1$. Let $$A= \{ r\in \mathbb{R} \ | \ \forall a\gt 0 \ \  f(r,a) \lt g(r,a) \}$$ and $$B= \{ r\in \mathbb{R} \ | \ \int_0^{+\infty} \exp(f(r,a))p(a)da \lt \int_0^{+\infty} \exp(g(r,a))p(a)da \}$$ Can we conclude that $A = B$?

**My try:** It's obvious that $A \subset B$ since $$f(r,a) \lt g(r,a) \implies \exp(f(r,a)) \lt \exp(g(r,a)) \implies p(a)\exp(f(r,a)) \lt p(a)\exp(g(r,a)) \\ \implies \int_0^{+\infty} p(a)\exp(f(r,a)) \lt \int_0^{+\infty} \exp(g(r,a))p(a)da$$ I don't know how to show that $B \subset A$: $$\int_0^{+\infty} \exp(f(r,a))p(a)da \lt \int_0^{+\infty} \exp(g(r,a))p(a)da \implies \int_0^{+\infty} [\exp(g(r,a)) - \exp(f(r,a))]p(a)da \gt 0$$
**Edit:** My main motivation for the question was the case $$f(r,a) = -\frac{(r-6a)^2}{72k} \text{and} \ \  g(r,a) = -\frac{(r-2a)^2}{8k}$$ where $k\gt0$ is a constant.

Comment: For $A \subset B$ you need to be slightly more careful since there could be $a$s for which $p(a) = 0$ and so you don't always have the *strict* inequality, but you don't have to do much to correct that.

Comment: @BrunoB You're right. In fact we are neglecting the sets of measure zero here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Counterexample 1**: Let $p(a)=e^{-a}$ and $f(r,a)=\sin(a), g(r,a)=\cos(a)$ then obviously $A=\emptyset$ and for every $r\in \mathbb R:$ $$\int_0^\infty e^{\sin(a)-a}\text da< \int_0^\infty e^{\cos(a)-a}\text da\implies B=\mathbb R.$$

**Counterexample 2**: Its not true even for the monotonic function just use $p$ like before and $f=a/2$ and $g=\sqrt a$.

**Note:** In general every couple of function $f,g$ such that $f(a_1)>g(a_1)$ and $f(a_2)>g(a_2)$ for some $a_1,a_2\in \mathbb R$ and that exists $\int e^fp\neq \int e^gp$, will produce produce a counterexample $("f(r,a)=f(a),g(r,a)=g(a)")$

**For the special case:** Lets assume that $p\ge0$ its a (general) function such that $\int p=1$ and the two known integral exists finite for every $r$.Now this functions have this property: $$\lim_{a\to 0}\frac{f(r,a)}{g(r,a)}=\lim_{a\to 0}\frac{(r-6a)^2}{9(r-2a)^2}=\begin{cases}1/9\;\;\text{if } r\neq 0\\ 1\;\;\text{if } r=0\end{cases} $$
and $f(r,a)>g(r,a)$ if and only if:$$ \frac{(r-6a)^2}{9(r-2a)^2}>1 \iff (r-6a)^2>9(r-2a)^2\iff $$ $$36a^2-12ar+r^2>9(4a^2-4ar+r^2)\iff $$ $$24ar>8r^2$$ $\implies \forall r>0$ there exists a certain $a$ such that $f(r,a)>g(r,a)$ and for the previous limit we know that there exists a neighborhood (when $r\neq 0$) such that $f(r,a)<g(r,a)\implies A\subset(-\infty,0]$. But there will definitely be values of $r>0$ such that the two integral are different i.e. $B\cap \mathbb R_+\neq \emptyset$ (for a proper choice of $p$, see "p.s.").

**P.S.** If you want (for a fixed $r>0$) $\int e^fp<\int e^gp$  just use a function $p(a)$ with support in $[0,\frac{8r^2}{24r}=\frac{r}{3})$ (because here $f<g$). If you want the contrary the $p$'s support has to be $(\frac{r}{3},\infty)$.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to derive a condition for which $B \subset A$?

Comment: I would advise to study this problem first: For which family of functions its true that  "$\int e^{f(a)}p(a)da<\int e^{g(a)}p(a)da\implies f<g$?". Because the set $A$ and $B$ depend too little on r except if you want add some $r$'s in the integral's.

Comment: I see. I've added a special case which was my motivation for the question. Do you think it's possible to find a counterexample for that case?

Comment: I added some ideas about the special case.

Comment: You showed that it's possible to construct $p(a)$ such that $B\cap \mathbb R_+\neq \emptyset$. Does this property hold for all $p(a)$ necessarily?

Comment: Also I think $24ar>8r^2$ should be $24ar<8r^2$.

Comment: No there are p choices such that one integral is larger than the other at will. I think that mine inequality its ok.